# How to merge customer names with transactions in a grouped SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

I have this customer ABC having multiple transaction. I want to merge the cells that have the same customer name and make it appear like on the image.

I am using select from where and group by customer_name at the end in my query.

I tried to use group by but didn't succeed.

Comment: "Merge" ... where? Which tool do you use? Reporting tools usually have option to move certain columns into "groups" which then result in output similar to what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer and want to use [SQL*Plus commands](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqpug/BREAK.html#GUID-8C5811BC-01DF-4D95-A3A0-5C42C546534F) to style the output from the query then use `BREAK` and `COMPUTE`:

```sql
BREAK ON customer_name
COMPUTE SUM OF total ON customer_name
SELECT customer_name,
       business_unit,
       transaction_nb,
       amount,
       total
FROM   table_name;
```

*Note: these are client-side commands specific to clients that support SQL*Plus commands that change how the output is formatted when displayed by the client; `BREAK` and `COMPUTE` are not SQL commands that are processed by the database.*

---

If you want to do it entirely in SQL then use `GROUP BY ROLLUP` and then use a `CASE` expression to blank out all of the `customer_name` values except the first in each group:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_name ORDER BY ROWNUM) = 1
       THEN customer_name
       END AS customer_name,
       business_unit,
       transaction_nb,
       amount,
       total
FROM   (
  SELECT customer_name,
         business_unit,
         transaction_nb,
         amount,
         SUM(total) AS total
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY ROLLUP(customer_name, business_unit, transaction_nb, amount)
  HAVING GROUPING_ID(customer_name, business_unit, transaction_nb, amount) IN (0, 15)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (customer_name, business_unit, transaction_nb, amount, total) AS
SELECT 'ABC', 'USA', 'XYZ11', 5000, 15000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'USA', 'YXY12', 2000, 20000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'USA', 'PXY13',  250, 30000 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CUSTOMER_NAME | BUSINESS_UNIT | TRANSACTION_NB | AMOUNT | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | USA | PXY13 | 250 | 30000 |
| *null* | USA | XYZ11 | 5000 | 15000 |
| *null* | USA | YXY12 | 2000 | 20000 |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 65000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kFyYS8fa)

Answer (score 0):

You can glue the fields you are to group via `CONCAT` in some format you can later on unpack and make them comma-separated via 'LISTAGG' and of course you will need to `GROUP BY Customer_name`.

```
SELECT
    Customer_name,
    SELECT LISTAGG(
        CONCAT(Business_unit, ';', TRANSACTION_NB, ';', Amount, ';', Total)
    , ',') as fields
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Customer_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The data provided and expected result are the same except the CUSTOMER_NAME column that is present just once and the position is centered verticaly and horisontaly within it's group and cell. Not quite understanding what is the purpose of this - below is the code that does the centerings. Please, note that the final result is highly dependant on tool you use and might need some adjustment from you too.
First the sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl (CUSTOMER_NAME, BUSINESS_UNIT, TRANSACTION_NB, AMOUNT, TOTAL) AS
        ( Select 'ABC', 'USA', 'XYZ11', 5000, 15000 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'USA', 'YXY12', 2000, 20000 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'USA', 'PXY13',  250, 30000 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC',  Null,  Null,   Null, 65000 From Dual 
        )
```

Since there is no obvious unique row identifier that could be used to preserve row ordering one is created as row number within the group. I used your TOTAL column for ordering cause it is in ascending order - you should use something else (there should be something) since this could be bad choice if the ascendance is not always kept.
Comments in code...

```sql
Select  Case  When Floor(AVG(RN) Over(Partition By CUSTOMER_NAME)) = RN -- <--- RN used to calc AVG num of rows Floored or Ceiled for decimal result to make a shift up or down
              Then Case When Length(CUSTOMER_NAME) >= LABEL_LEN         -- <--- If name length longer then or equal to label length - leave it as it is
                        Then CUSTOMER_NAME
                   Else LPAD(' ', Floor((LABEL_LEN - Length(CUSTOMER_NAME))/2), ' ') ||  -- <-- else left add spaces (half of difference between name and label) 
                        CUSTOMER_NAME ||                                                 -- <-- for decimal values use ceil/floor to make the shift left or right
                        LPAD(' ', CEIL((LABEL_LEN - Length(CUSTOMER_NAME))/2), ' ')  -- <-- this you don't need (it is other half right added)
                   End                                                               -- <-- it's here just in case 
        End "CUSTOMER_NAME",
        BUSINESS_UNIT,TRANSACTION_NB, AMOUNT, TOTAL
From    ( Select  ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By CUSTOMER_NAME Order By TOTAL) "RN", Length('CUSTOMER_NAM') "LABEL_LEN",
                  CUSTOMER_NAME, BUSINESS_UNIT, TRANSACTION_NB, AMOUNT, TOTAL, CUSTOMER_NAME "CUST_NM"  -- <-- CUST_NM just for sort - use your own
          From    tbl
        )
Order By  CUST_NM, RN -- <-- you should use your own sort
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
CUSTOMER_NAME BUSINESS_UNIT TRANSACTION_NB AMOUNT TOTAL
------------- ------------- -------------- ------ -----
              USA             XYZ11          5000 15000
     ABC      USA             YXY12          2000 20000
              USA             PXY13           250 30000
                                                  65000   */
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
```

This query is enough for you. you are trying to select your transitions as an object.I think,it is not the right approach.You should format your data in  api response or in the client side. 
*(don't use (*) to select, replace with your columns)*